# Can't disable Alt+Grave in 16.04

Tags: unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, ccsm

I have two situations:

One - where I have <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> set. If <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> is in use on my keyboard settings, it will set 2 rules according to CompizConfig. If I disable **Rotate Cube** rules. Nothing changes. I still can't use the rule for my own desires.

[image: Rotate Cube in CCSM]

[image: keyboard settings]

Two - where I remove the rule that I do not want <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> to work for, it removes all the rules.

[image: no alt-grave in CCSM]

[image: keyboard settings]

Below is what <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> opens if the rules are on.

[image: window switcher]

No matter what I set my rules to, <kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>`</kbd> always works. How can I get it so I can set this shortcut to something?

[image: dconf editor]

[image: dconf editor]